# Profiler QT application for windows

Tags: windows, qt, profiler

Hi I am looking for a profiler application to profile a QT application for Windows. Currently, I tried with Parallel Studio from Intel, but I got a lot false positive.

Any link or doc to start?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

http://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-cache-profiler.html

Qt Creator it self have an profiler built in, just check the link above to read about them.

Comment: Agus asked about profilers for Windows.
Here the list of profilers for Linux and Windows. https://wiki.qt.io/Profiling_and_Memory_Checking_Tools
I used Very Sleepy, really simple one.